# WPF WebBrowser Control - no LinkClicked event

Tags: wpf, event-handling, webbrowser-control

Does someone have know how to trap clicks on Links in the WPF WebBrowser Control?

I need to get the links target, when the link is clicked, before the Page is navigating.

Any inputs highly appreciated!

**My solution in Code** As proposed for simple Links this would be achieved with the following code:

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    //prefix must be lowercase (ssrs conforms to web-standards and makes things lowercase)
            string myPrefix = "http://myPrefix";

            //check if target starts with the prefix
            if (e.Uri.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith(myPrefix))
            {
                //cancel Navigation
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
}
```

Thank you for hepling me out on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attache an event handler to the Navigating event. Extract the link , execute your logic before the page is navigated.

Cheers.

Comment: But sometimes link clicking does not cause navigation, but executes a javascript handler.

Comment: Thank you two

@DrakeVN, I did try to get all the links in the loaded Page in the Navigated event, and there adding events for every single Link. But this gets a bit hairy as one needs to work with many com_objects. And a lot seemed to change, compared to the WebBrowser Control in Windows Forms. I'll try your simpler approach.

@STO: links with javascript handlers shouldn't be a problem in my case, as I use the trapped links in Reporting Services to open the according elements.

Comment: @STO if the javaScript handler does some processing and then do a window.open, is there a way to catch that opening and then display that Url within the scope of container application, perhaps in a new instance of WebBrowser control

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about that, but may be MessageHook event helps you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndhost.messagehook.aspx

Comment: Tahnks, I guess there should be a simpler way, and the following doesnt allow me to use it:

Security Note 
This type or member is not available in the Internet security zone.

Answer (score 0):

Control your clicks in the WebBrowser Navigating events handler. You can create this in Xal or in the constructor and use the following method:

```
    private void webBrowser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // The WebBrowser control is checking the Uri 
        if (e.Uri.ToString() != "Place your url string here") //ex: "http://stackoverflow.com"
        {
            // Uri is not the same so it cancels the process
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```